# Laplace transform using the definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Find the Laplace of the given function using the definition

$$f(t)=tsin(t)$$

I know what the answer is according to a sheet that I have of common transforms but I am not 100% on how to get there using the definition.

I know that if the question were to be:
$$f(t)= sin(t)$$
then it's a simple $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}*sin(t)$$
which by integration by parts give you $$1/((s-1)^2-1)$$

But how do I do it with the additional t??

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: I was not aware of this. Thank you. I'm not trying to spam, just trying to get my homework done and study for a test! I'm admittedly semi-taking the easy way out, but I learn best from examples, and without the correct answer, I am not really sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\int_0^\infty t\sin(t)\mathrm e^{-st}\mathrm dt=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\int_0^\infty \sin(t)\mathrm e^{-st}\mathrm dt$$
Beware though that the formula you give for
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin(t)\mathrm e^{-st}\mathrm dt$$
is inaccurate.

Comment: Totally forgot about the derivative part. Thanks! That's all I needed:)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write $\sin t = {1 \over 2 i } (e^{it} - e^{-it})$. If we let $r(t) = t 1_{(0,1)}(t)$, it is straightforward to establish that ${\cal L} r(s) = {1 \over s^2}$ (that is, the Laplace transform of a ramp).

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
{\cal L} f(s) &=& \int_0^\infty e^{-st} {1 \over 2 i } (e^{it} - e^{-it}) t dt \\
&=& {1 \over 2 i } ( \int_0^\infty e^{-(s-i)t}t dt - \int_0^\infty e^{-(s+i)t}t dt ) \\
&=& {1 \over 2 i } ( {\cal L} r(s-i) - {\cal L} r(s+i) ) \\
&=& \cdots
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: You mean "If we let $r(t)=t1_{(0,\infty)}(t)$", right?

Comment: @Did: Indeed! Thanks for catching that.